# Create a new process and check for a variable in the parent process in bash/python

Tags: python, bash, fork

Here is what I want to do in pseudo code:

```
    create process 
    {
        while not (answer == yes in parent process)
        {
            mplayer alert.mp3
        }
    }

    show dialog "Time is up! Press 'yes' to stop the alarm."
    answer = get userinput
```

---

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    sleep $1
    lockfile=$(mktemp)
    {
        while [[ -f "$lockfile" ]]
        do
            kdialog --passivepopup 'Time is up!' 1
            sleep 1
        done
    }&

    kdialog --msgbox 'Time is up! Leave this dialog to stop notifications.'
    rm $lockfile
```

Thanks to @abeaumet

Comment: Forks are not threads, they do not share memory. You will need to write and read a file or something similar.

Comment: Well, some means of interprocess communication at least.  Perhaps a socketpair before the fork, with each subsequent process closing one end and retaining the other.  Also the pseudocode does't use fork() properly.

Answer (score 1):

As the variable you want to share seems to be a boolean, you can base yourself on the presence or absence of a temporary file.

A concrete example with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create a lock file to permit communication (act as your bool variable)
LOCKFILE=`mktemp /tmp/scriptXXXX`

# Fork a subprocess in background
{
  # While the lockfile exists, wait
  while [ -f "$LOCKFILE" ] ; do sleep 1 ; done

  # When the file no longer exists, this is the signal from the main process
  echo 'File removed! Play music!'
} &

# Do some long stuff in main process...
sleep 5

# Delete the lockfile (child wait for it)
rm -f "$LOCKFILE" &>/dev/null

exit 0
```